# Zend Studio and Drupal

Tags: drupal, zend-studio

Hi I am trying out Zend Studio for Drupal module development. Of course, my module code does not explicitly include Drupal files (since obviously it runs under the Drupal bootstrap context.)

I want Zend to recognize this and resolve function calls to the appropriate Drupal files. I tried adding the Drupal source files under Build Path>Link Source. I then get this message:

"Creating the folder will result in a conflict: Cannot nest 'subsites/drupal-6.20' inside 'myproject'. To enable the nesting exclude 'drupal-6.20/' from 'myproject' .

Of course, if I exclude drupal-6.20 folder that defeats the purpose. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

right click project > properties > PHP Include Path > Libraries > Add External Source Folder > select the folder where drupal is installed

Answer (score 1):

For Zend Studio 10.0 goto

1) Windows -> Preferences -> General (in window that open) -> Content Type -> Text (in side pane) -> %content-type.name.0 -> Add.. (in pane below)

a popup up window appear for you to add any extension you wish to add in.

Restart Zend and you are good to play ...